# Console Display for System.out.println(refVar name)

Tags: java

How can System.out.println(refVar name) give the output shown by this example's website? I understand why "Simcard object constructed" gets displayed, but why do the remaining fields get displayed in that specific order: "New Sim card constructed for nokia 1100."

My understanding is that fields can't just be outputted by calling a reference name.

(http://www.hubberspot.com/2012/07/how-composition-has-relationship-works.html)

```
class SimCard {

   private String cardNumber;

   public SimCard(){

 System.out.println("SimCard Object Constructed");
 cardNumber = "New SimCard Constructed";

   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {

 return cardNumber;

   } 
             }

public class Mobile {

   private SimCard sim = new SimCard();
   private String mobile = "Nokia";
   private int model = 1100;

   @Override
   public String toString() {

 return sim + " for " + mobile + " " + model;

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

 Mobile mob = new Mobile();
 System.out.println(mob);

       }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mobile/model are getting created when you create the new instance

```
Mobile mob = new Mobile()
```

They get set to their defaults as specified in the class. 
Then when you output the class the overidden String method is called which returns the output to main and it is printed.